# MenuPickerStyle not working on Mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, swiftui

According to the Apple Developer Documentation `MenuPickerStyle` is defined as:

> A picker style that presents the options as a menu when the user presses a button, or as a submenu when nested within a larger menu.

Using an example below, I can get the behaviour I want on iOS, but not when running the same example on Mac Catalyst target, even though the documentation states support for it.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    enum Fruit: Int, CaseIterable {
        case apple
        case orange
        case plum
    }
    
    @State private var selectedFruit: Fruit = .apple
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Select a fruit", selection: $selectedFruit) {
            ForEach(Fruit.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { fruit in
                Text(String(describing: fruit).capitalized).tag(fruit)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

Running this code on macOS displays the actual label and the value, but the actual picker presentation is not working after tapping on the value. Am I missing something here?

[image: macOS Picker Presentation issue]

Answer (score 2):

Only right click works. It's not a bug, it's a feature.